# code source of qr-code generator windows store

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

i am trying to create qr-code picture with "zxing tools" and save the picture of qr-code in app.

however i can't find any simple function.

and i found this simple code that i can't make it to save the picture as png in the app.

i think i am missing two extra line of code to save picture from this code.

```
     var writer = new ZXing.QrCode.QRCodeWriter();
     var matrix = writer.encode("text to qr-code ", BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 50, 50);
     var bitmap = matrix.ToBitmap(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example of generator Qr-code without using zing tool

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Generate-QR-Codes-on-cdac562f/view/Discussions